# Inverse of a block 2x2 matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

How to solve this type of problem:
We've got a block 2x2 matrix :
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}A_{11}&A_{12}\\A_{21}&A_{22}\\\end{bmatrix}$$
If matrices $A$ and $A_{22}$ are invertible, show that a matrix $B = A_{11} - A_{12}A_{22}^{-1}A_{21}$is also invertible.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

Observe that for a $2 \times 2$ matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ the claim follows from $(ad - bc)/d = a - bd^{-1}c$.

Let vertical bars indicate a determinant. Then
\begin{align}
|A_{22}|^{-1}|A|  &= \begin{vmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & A_{22}^{-1}\end{vmatrix}\begin{vmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21}& A_{22}\end{vmatrix}
 = \begin{vmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{22}^{-1}A_{21} & I \end{vmatrix}\\
& = \begin{vmatrix} I & A_{12} \\ 0 & I \end{vmatrix}\ \begin{vmatrix} A_{11} - A_{12}A_{22}^{-1}A_{21} & 0 \\ A_{22}^{-1}A_{21} & I \end{vmatrix} = |A_{11} - A_{12}A_{22}^{-1}A_{21}|,
\end{align}
from which the claim follows.